# Retrieve all individuals based on Data Property Assertions

Tags: sparql, protege

I am trying to retrieve information based on Data Property Assertions in Protege (SPARQL Query), however, my code is not working. I am trying to get all individuals that were born after 1960.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?person ?birthYear
WHERE {
  ?a rdfs:label ?person .
  ?person xsd:hasBirthYear ?birthYear .
  FILTER(?birthYear>=1960)
}
```

Comment: Hi there! It looked like you were trying to add a screenshot to your question, but it didn't show up because you can't link to a local file, you need to upload it somewhere on the web first. I removed the link and improved the formatting of your question.

Comment: I would also recommend that you edit your question to show some of the data that you are querying. It's hard to say why a query is not working without seeing the data.

Comment: Besides the comment from @cygri regarding showing sample data, do **not** hijack existing vocabularies like XSD, OWL, RDF etc. like you did here with `xsd:hasBirthYear` - use your own namespace or reuse existing vocabularies.

Comment: and just a guess: either i ) the property `hasBirthYear` that you created in Protege does **not** have the XSD namepace but something else (check the full URI of this property) or ii) the values of `hasBirthYear` are not integer values. But honestly, I'm pretty sure that the URI of the property is just wrong. When you create a new ontology by default a much longer namespace is set, something like `http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2019/04/...` probably